# 3d image compression with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, compression, svd

I have a 3d numpy array representing an object with cells as voxels and the voxels having values from 1 to 10. I would like to compress the image (a) to make it smaller and (b) to get a quick idea later on of how complex the image is by compressing it to a minimum level of agreement with the original image.

I have used SVD to do this with 2D images and seeing how many singular values were required but it looks to have difficulty with 3D ones. If e.g. I look at the diagonal terms in the S matrix, they are all zero and I was expecting singular values.

Is there any way I can use svd to compress 3D arrays (e.g. flattening in some way)? Or are other methods more appropriate? If necessary I could probably simplify the voxel values to 0 or 1.

Comment: You could  create a set of 2d sparse matrices that would track the position and value for each of the sub arrays along the first dimension of your 3d matrix

Answer (score 2):

You could essentially apply the same principle to the 3D data without flattening it. There are some algorithms to separate N-dimensional matrices, such as the CP-ALS (using Alternating Least Squares) and this is implemented in the package [sktensor](https://github.com/mnick/scikit-tensor). You can use the package to decompose the tensor given a *rank*:

```
from sktensor import dtensor, cp_als
T = dtensor(X)
rank = 5
P, fit, itr, exectimes = cp_als(T, rank, init='random')
```

With `X` being your data. You could then use the weights `weights = P.lmbda` to reconstruct the original array `X` and calculate the reconstruction error, as you would do with SVD.

Other decomposition methods for 3D data (or in general tensors) include the [Tucker Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tucker_decomposition) or the Canonical Decomposition (also available in the same package).

It is not directly a 3D SVD, but all the methods above can be used to analyze the principal components of your data.

Find bellow (just for completeness) an image of the tucker decomposition:

[image]

And bellow another image of the decomposition that CP-ALS (optimization algorithm) tries to obtain:

[image]

Image credits to:

1- http://www.slideshare.net/KoheiHayashi1/talk-in-jokyonokai-12989223

2- http://www.bsp.brain.riken.jp/~zhougx/tensor.html

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [higher order svd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition)/[Tucker decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tucker_decomposition).

In the 3D case, you will get three projection matrices (one for each dimension) and a low rank core tensor (a 3D array).

You can do this easily using [TensorLy](https://tensorly.github.io/stable/tensor_decomposition.html#tucker):

```
from tensorly.decomposition import tucker
core, factors = tucker(tensor, ranks=[2, 3, 4])
```

Here, `core` will have shape (2, 3, 4) and `len(factors)` will be `3`, one factor for each dimension.